# What is wrong with my code PhysicsRemoveExample.java (AndEngine)?

Tags: java, android, andengine, physics-engine

Trying to make the example `PhysicsRemoveExample.java` from [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsRemoveExample.java?r=18648ed40c65722c602591b2ae6769315fdfe134).

I get this message when the program starts:

```
Sorry! The application PhysicsRemoveExample(process org.anddev.andengine.PhysicsRemoveExample) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

I have Build Path `andengine.jar` and `andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar`
`assets/gfx -> face_box_tiled.png` and `face_circle_tiled.png`.

This is my Java code in `PhysicsRemoveExample.java`. Same as in the example, though I have changed to `extends BaseGameActivity`.

```
package org.anddev.andengine.PhysicsRemoveExample;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.IOnAreaTouchListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.ITouchArea;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.sensor.accelerometer.AccelerometerData;
import org.anddev.andengine.sensor.accelerometer.IAccelerometerListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;


/**
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich
 * @since 18:47:08 - 19.03.2010
 */
public class PhysicsRemoveExample extends BaseGameActivity implements IAccelerometerListener, IOnSceneTouchListener, IOnAreaTouchListener {
        // ===========================================================
        // Constants
        // ===========================================================


        private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
        private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;


        // ===========================================================
        // Fields
        // ===========================================================


        private Texture mTexture;


        private TiledTextureRegion mBoxFaceTextureRegion;
        private TiledTextureRegion mCircleFaceTextureRegion;


        private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;


        private int mFaceCount = 0;


        private final Vector2 mTempVector = new Vector2();


        // ===========================================================
        // Constructors
        // ===========================================================


        // ===========================================================
        // Getter & Setter
        // ===========================================================


        // ===========================================================
        // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
        // ===========================================================


        @Override
        public Engine onLoadEngine() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Touch the screen to add objects. Touch an object to remove it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);


                final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
                engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);


                return new Engine(engineOptions);
        }


        @Override
        public void onLoadResources() {
                this.mTexture = new Texture(64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
                TextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
                this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "face_box_tiled.png", 0, 0, 2, 1); // 64x32
                this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "face_circle_tiled.png", 0, 32, 2, 1); // 64x32
                this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);


                this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
        }


        @Override
        public Scene onLoadScene() {
                this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());


                final Scene scene = new Scene(2);
                scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0, 0, 0));
                scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);


                this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);


                final Shape ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2);
                final Shape roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2);
                final Shape left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
                final Shape right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT);


                final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
                PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
                PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
                PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
                PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);


                scene.getBottomLayer().addEntity(ground);
                scene.getBottomLayer().addEntity(roof);
                scene.getBottomLayer().addEntity(left);
                scene.getBottomLayer().addEntity(right);


                scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);


                scene.setOnAreaTouchListener(this);


                return scene;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final ITouchArea pTouchArea, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        PhysicsRemoveExample.this.removeFace((AnimatedSprite)pTouchArea);
                        return true;
                }


                return false;
        }


        public void onLoadComplete() {


        }


        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
                if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
                        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                this.addFace(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
                                return true;
                        }
                }
                return false;
        }


        @Override
        public void onAccelerometerChanged(final AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {
                this.mTempVector.set(pAccelerometerData.getY(), pAccelerometerData.getX());


                this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(this.mTempVector);
        }


        // ===========================================================
        // Methods
        // ===========================================================


        private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
                final Scene scene = this.mEngine.getScene();


                this.mFaceCount++;


                final AnimatedSprite face;
                final Body body;


                final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);


                if(this.mFaceCount % 2 == 0) {
                        face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion);
                        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
                } else {
                        face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion);
                        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
                }


                face.animate(200, true);
                face.setUpdatePhysics(false);


                scene.registerTouchArea(face);
                scene.getTopLayer().addEntity(face);
                this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true, false, false));
        }


        private void removeFace(final AnimatedSprite face) {
                final Scene scene = this.mEngine.getScene();


                final PhysicsConnector facePhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(face);


                this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(facePhysicsConnector);
                this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(facePhysicsConnector.getBody());


                scene.unregisterTouchArea(face);
                scene.getTopLayer().removeEntity(face);
        }


        // ===========================================================
        // Inner and Anonymous Classes
        // ===========================================================
}
```

And I get this error in LogCat:

```
11-12 20:31:39.482: ERROR/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
11-12 20:31:39.482: ERROR/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
11-12 20:31:39.482: ERROR/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
11-12 20:31:39.482: ERROR/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
11-12 20:31:55.381: ERROR/BatteryService(52): usbOnlinePath not found
11-12 20:31:55.381: ERROR/BatteryService(52): batteryVoltagePath not found
11-12 20:31:55.381: ERROR/BatteryService(52): batteryTemperaturePath not found
11-12 20:31:55.401: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(52): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
11-12 20:32:01.131: ERROR/EventHub(52): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
11-12 20:32:01.131: ERROR/EventHub(52): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
11-12 20:32:01.351: ERROR/System(52): Failure starting core service
11-12 20:32:01.351: ERROR/System(52): java.lang.SecurityException
11-12 20:32:01.351: ERROR/System(52):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
11-12 20:32:01.351: ERROR/System(52):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
11-12 20:32:01.351: ERROR/System(52):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
11-12 20:32:01.351: ERROR/System(52):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
11-12 20:32:01.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(52): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
11-12 20:32:12.683: ERROR/ActivityThread(103): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
11-12 20:32:15.853: ERROR/ActivityThread(103): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
11-12 20:32:16.183: ERROR/ActivityThread(103): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
11-12 20:32:17.303: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(31): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
11-12 20:32:17.313: ERROR/MediaPlayer(52): Unable to to create media player
11-12 20:32:23.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(135): ERROR: thread attach failed
11-12 20:32:32.292: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(178): ERROR: thread attach failed
11-12 20:32:59.373: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at org.anddev.andengine.PhysicsRemoveExample.PhysicsRemoveExample.onLoadScene(PhysicsRemoveExample.java:125)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:159)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:83)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:1969)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3731)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:657)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library andenginephysicsbox2dextension not found
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     at org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:30)
11-12 20:32:59.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(225):     ... 15 more
11-12 20:32:59.603: ERROR/dalvikvm(225): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

What is wrong? Have tried with emulator 1.6 and 2.1 and created a whole new AVD.
I could do the [Getting Started Tutorial (Video – 5 minutes)](http://www.andengine.org/blog/2010/06/andengine-getting-started-tutorial-video/) without any problems.

Answer (score 5):

Check if libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so file is in your libs/armeabi folder

Comment: The UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library andenginephysicsbox2dextension not found is the key

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to get the physics working in Eclipse:::

1.
Run and install:
Mercurial-2.1.exe

1. The Mercurial-2.1 gives you the HG command tool.
2. Use the hg tool at the command(DOS) prompt to obtain the latest AndEngine 
   and andenginephysicsbox2dextension. Use the following hg commands>

hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/

hg clone https://andengine.googlecode.com/hg/ andengine

1. This will download the two projects. Import them into Eclipse.
   Use FILE -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace -> select root directory -> BROWSE
   Find the AndEngine project downloaded with the hg command.
   Do the same for the andenginephysicsbox2dextension project - so you will have two library projects
   in Eclipse.
2. You will probably have to right-click on the project and set "Project Build target" to
   Android 2.3. You will also probably need to create a res and gen folder in the root of the project.
   Make sure the project is compiled.
3. Right-click project and choose Export -> under Java select the "jar file" option. 
   Click NEXT. 
   UNTICK EVERYTHING in the right hand pane - where is says AndroidManifest.xml and everything else in that 
   list uncheck it. specify a location for the .jar file for example if you are compiling the AndEngine.jar
   you might enter : C:\temp\andengine.jar
   in the jar file input box. Click FINISH - it should compile.
4. Goto to this site:

   http://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/source/browse/libs/?name=ed03082d4a&r=38406ae958c5f5ed89e2e73e9e71385c242e8e28#libs%2Farmeabi-v7a%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Download the two .so files these will need to go into :
armeabi
armeabi-v7a

1. The .jar files go in the lib folder off the root.
   The .so files --- create a folder called libs off the root.
   Under the libs folder create two folders armeabi AND armeabi-v7a -- The .so files go in these two folders.

Comment: But after copied this lib file application will not be launch. Application started but close without any display.

Comment: The Google Code repositories are now outdated, AndEngine and all of the extensions are on GitHub: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/

Answer (score 0):

just copy the "libs" file -not the "lib" file- from the andengine examples project and paste it into your project.

Answer (score 0):

And Old andengine.jar  andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar  remvove.

And  copy the  "lib" and "libs"  folder - from the andengine examples project and paste it into your project.and add lib inner jar file Add to build path

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and was not able to do any thing with this problem occurring. again and again.

Ahh at last I was able to solve the problem and want to share because there must be may whop must have loose tonns of there hairs :)

I just replace the one from nicolas repo to  RealMayo repo. Below is the link
    https://github.com/RealMayo/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.

Please let me know.
     :)

Happy coding.