# Exception Running Android App with And Engine

Tags: android, exception, animation, 2d, andengine

I got source of my app from a third party and unfortunately I could not get assistance from person who was working on this app previously.
It uses And Engine source code for 2d things.

When I run app it gives exception java.language.ExceptionInInitializerError.

There is may be cause of missing .so files in libs/armeabi folder as I do not have any .so files in that folder. This suggestion was mentioned in this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168843/what-is-wrong-with-my-code-physicsremoveexample-java-andengine)

Please help me out in this issue as I could not see app running properly untill that I could not fix other bugs in it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.andengine.org/forums/physics-box2d-extension/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-t2683.html) might help.

And you can get the .so files in [this thread](http://www.andengine.org/forums/physics-box2d-extension/yet-another-unsatisfiedlinkexception-t5544.html) I have created one ago, I have put the link in there.

Comment: Thank you for responsing so quickly. And finally it runs successfully by including .so files that you let me download links provided in your answer. Also would you provide some examples or tutorial for getting started on And Engine since I want to learn basics of And Engine.

Comment: The tutorial forum - http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/ - is full of great tutorials, like this one: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/simple-andengine-game-updated-21-10-2011-t5145.html which is great imo, creating a game from scratch and showing the whole path. I used it to get started. And you should read more tutorials from that section.

Comment: Thank You for supporting me on this